# Can I have trailing strings after a @PathParam in jersey1?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In a jersey-1 application I have a resource annotated as:

```
@GET @Path("/root/{someID}/bar")
public FooBar getFooBar(@PathParam("someID") String fooID) {
    ...
}

@GET @Path("/root/{someID}/baz")
public FooBaz getFooBaz(@PathParam("someID") String fooID) {
    ...
}
```

and I get errors on startup like this

```
Illegal URI template for sub-resource method ... getFooBar(...): Illegal character '/'
```

Is it legal to have trailing data after the `@PathParams`?

Comment: I can see no problem with your code. Is this the real code you use?

Comment: I'm using jersey1.14 @Path("ex/{id1}/EE") is working

Comment: Whooops, I was missing a closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@GET @Path("/root/{someID}/bar/{bar}")
```